# When the page width is used it jumps down instead of creating a horizontal overflow

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have content on my page in boxes.

They are displayed like this.

```
Box1  Box2  Box3  Box4
```

And then if I add anymore it jumps down and creates a vertical overflow.

But I want it to have a horizontal scroll bar.

This is how the wrapper is in css.

```
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9vvtg/

Just need to add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to the container

Comment: I have got a image from the design of what it looks like also looks the same in code and the little bar at the bottom will be the scroll bar when this is fixed. http://i50.tinypic.com/mkcf1c.png

Comment: Got it working I was using float left to keep them align but now it is working im using display inline-block to keep them align this just broke one thing which is my p tag which is holding content at a centern width and making a new line thank.

Answer (score 0):

The width of `#content` is referencing the width of its parent, most likely the viewport. If you need a horizontal scroll, set an explicit width. If you know the width of the containing elements, just do the math and set the width to match, or be lazy and set it wider.

```
/* there are four of these */
.insides { 
     width: 200px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
}

#content {
     width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: I would try that but there is going to be more than 4 it will be in a while loop so it is however many get outputted. So it will need to hold as much so that would not work :/